# How to parse Json response into a simple array, not the array of objects (for Canvas.js)?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, canvas, canvasjs

So I'm using Canvas.js to build a chart, and I want datapoints in this chart to be taken from the Json response I get earlier in my script. 
At the moment my code looks as follows:

```
$.post('admin/weekly_websites/json', data, function(response){
    points = $.parseJSON(response);
    console.log(response);
});
var chart_websites_week = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainerWebsitesWeekly", {
    animationEnabled: true,
    height: 300,
    width: 600,
    title: {
        text: 'Websites'
    },
    data: [              
        {
            type: "line",
            dataPoints: points
        }
    ]
});
chart_websites_week.render();
```

And it does not seem to work. It is said in CanvasJs documentation that datapoints could be taken from variable, but this variable should be an array like:

```
dataPoints: [
    {label: 'tomato', y: 8},
    {...}
]
```

My Json response lloks as follows:

```
[{"label":"2016-04-03","y":58},{"label":"2016-04-06","y":43}]
```

And when I try to parse it, I get an array of objects, and nothing gets shown on my chart. But if I copy this string from console log and just put it in dataPoints, everything works fine.
How could I parse Json NOT in object array, or what could be an other solution to my problem?
Would highly appreciate any possible help!

Comment: Are you sure that you try to render AFTER you have received the JSON? From your code it is not clear, if render() is called after post() has finished.

Comment: yep, that was the problem, I added timeout to chart rendering and everything is workink great. thank you @Nils

Comment: You should use the success() function of post() instead of timeout, but for testing timeout is sufficient... maybe read into js promises.